# How can I plot graph in different position in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, subplot

I have these four datasets like df1. and I want to print them into scatter diagram like 2*2.

```
df1
    Height  time_of_day resolution  clusters
11  3.146094    0.458333    0.594089    0
90  0.191690    0.541667    0.594089    0
99  1.300386    1.666667    0.594089    1
121 3.054903    2.083333    0.594089    0

df2
    Height  time_of_day resolution  clusters
10  3.146094    0.458333    0.594089    0
60  3.191690    0.541667    0.594089    0
87  1.300386    1.666667    0.594089    1
121 3.054903    1.083333    0.594089    0

df3
    Height  time_of_day resolution  clusters
13  3.146094    0.458333    0.594089    0
61  3.191690    0.541667    0.594089    0
86  1.300386    1.666667    0.594089    1
113 4.054903    1.083333    0.594089    0

df4
    Height  time_of_day resolution  clusters
10  3.146094    0.458333    0.594089    0
20  3.191690    0.541667    0.594089    0
37  1.300386    1.666667    0.594089    1
121 3.054903    1.083333    0.594089    0
```

I have tried several methods and all of them was not work.

```
dics = [df1,df2,df3,df4]
rows = range(4)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2,squeeze=False,figsize = (20,10))
for x in rows:
    for i,dic in enumerate(dics):
        sns.lmplot(x="time_of_day", y="Height",fit_reg=False,hue="clusters", data=dic[x], height=6, aspect=1.5)

plt.show()
```

And this is the single code for scatter plot

```
sns.lmplot(x="time_of_day", y="Height",fit_reg=False,hue="clusters", data=summer_spike_df, height=6, aspect=1.5)
```

What code should I change in order to print into 2*2 with different results of scatter plot?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not plotting the regression line, then why not just use [`seaborn.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html).

You can use the `zip` function and [`array.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel) to plot using:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,squeeze=False,figsize = (20,10))

for df, ax in zip(dics, axes.ravel()):
    sns.scatterplot(x="time_of_day", y="Height",hue="clusters", data=df, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! thank you for the answer, just for one thing, I would like to change the color.. for mine it shows very bright purple.. I tried color = "red" inside the sns.scatterplot. but it's not working. Do you have an idea? thank you!

Comment: Try using the `palette` argument inside the `scatterplot` method. eg `palette=['r', 'g']`

Comment: @PythonRunner no problem buddy, happy coding